# General construction of enveloping C*-algebra, left/right-regular representation, etc

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In a number of contexts (e.g. groups, crossed products, groupoids, Fell bundles) there are similar constructions of enveloping C*-algebras and left/right-regular representations that incorporate intertwining operators, subrepresentations, cyclicity, matrix coefficient functions, etc. Is there a generalized version of this construction?